# Username contain Specific word in Twitter API Using Java

Tags: java, twitter

How can I search for a word in twitter's users?

for example how can I find all users who has in their names or usernames the word "James"?

If I use `twitter.showUser(username)` it will return a single user IF IT EXISTS!

I want all the users who may contain `username` in their usernames or names. I'm using Twitter4J in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the way to go:

1. Get a list of all available users (http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/4.0.0/twitter4j/api/UsersResources.html#searchUsers-java.lang.String-int-)
2. Iterate `data.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.name.contains('James')).collect(toList)`

Comment: how to get all users? the method you are talking about does not exist!

Comment: Use this https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search

Comment: In twitter4J, I can not do that.

Comment: Look here http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/4.0.0/twitter4j/api/UsersResources.html#searchUsers-java.lang.String-int-

Comment: there are no such method as getAllUsers, but the link helped me out! Thank you